# Are any of the Mass Effect 1 DLCs relevant to the story in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2, mass-effect

I'm asking here because I don't want spoilers. Just yes or no answers. In case of "yes", please, tell me what DLC should I play and in what order.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mass Effect 1's "Bring Down the Sky" has an effect in Mass Effect 2 and 3. The other available DLC, "Pinnacle Station", does not.

You've asked to avoid spoilers, so I'll simply say that the default canon is that Bring Down the Sky ends with the Renegade ending. If you play it personally, you can alter this.

Comment: Your answer is perfect ::- ). Thank you. I'll get on and play BDtS.